# Upload a file to a varbinary with SQL Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, file, upload, ssms, varbinary

Is there any way to upload a file to a varbinary with SQL Management Studio without writting a manual SQL query ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

use OPENROWSET

example

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
GO
CREATE TABLE myTable(FileName nvarchar(60), 
  FileType nvarchar(60), Document varbinary(max));
GO

INSERT INTO myTable(FileName, FileType, Document) 
   SELECT 'Text1.txt' AS FileName, 
      '.txt' AS FileType, 
      * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\Text1.txt', SINGLE_BLOB) AS Document;
GO
```

Comment: OK but is there a way without SQL query ? With the GUI ?

Comment: caveat from [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql) this example was stolen from: requires the `ADMINISTER BULK OPERATIONS` permission

Answer (score 7):

In short, using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), no.

The options are to either complete your task via T-SQL or to roll your own solution/application.

A solution devised using SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) may also be possible.